# Asp.Net MVC 3 DropDownListFor, any way to always show the OptionLabel default

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, drop-down-menu, html-helper

In MVC 3 I have a Html.DropDownListFor which works very well. It works like it's bound to the Model so when I change to something specific the model changes as well.

The problem is that for cosmetic reasons I wan't to have the OptionLabel always be the one shown not the actual value. So the DropDownList will be chosen to select the value but doesn't have to display the value.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom dropdown list developing an extension method of the helper Html.

Comment: Sure, but I don't even know what is required in HTML to set this up this way. I'll check it out.